# Concatenate two numpy arrays so that index order keeps the same?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume I have two numpy arrays as follows:

```
{0: array([ 2, 4, 8, 9, 12], dtype=int64),
1: array([ 1, 3, 5], dtype=int64)}
```

Now I want to replace each array with the ID at the front, i.e. the values in array 0 become 0 and in array 1 become 1, then both arrays should be merged, whereby the index order must be correct.
I.e. desired output:

```
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0])
```

But that's what I get:

```
np.concatenate((h1,h2), axis=0)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

(Each array contains only unique values, if this helps.)

How can this be done?

Comment: `concatenate` just joins arrays end-to-end (on the selected dimension).  It isn't a merge.  I think you need to make a `results` array of the final size (eg `np.zeros(10)`), and assign values from the two arrays (or maybe just array1) to the right slots.  `np.nonzero(dict[1])` might help.

Comment: I don't see how would get the desired output from the 2 source arrays.  What do you mean by `index order`?  There's no inherent index order in `numpy`, just [0,1,2....]`.

Comment: After reading your explanation, I would expect to get the result that you are getting `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`. You have to be more clear about what you want. _Your_ desired result (`[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0]`)makes no sense, at least in relation to your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
d = {0: array([ 2, 4, 8, 9, 12], dtype=int64),
     1: array([ 1, 3, 5], dtype=int64)}

(np.concatenate([d[0],d[1]]).argsort(kind="stable")>=len(d[0])).view(np.uint8)
# array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Exactly, what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of merging is a bit unclear.  But here's something that makes sense

```
In [399]: dd ={0: np.array([ 2, 4, 8, 9, 12]), 
     ...: 1: np.array([ 1, 3, 5])}                                                             

In [403]: res = np.zeros(13, int)                                                              
In [404]: res[dd[0]] = 0                                                                       
In [405]: res[dd[1]] = 1                                                                       
In [406]: res                                                                                  
Out[406]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Or to make the assignments clearer:

```
In [407]: res = np.zeros(13, int)                                                              
In [408]: res[dd[0]] = 2                                                                       
In [409]: res[dd[1]] = 1                                                                       
In [410]: res                                                                                  
Out[410]: array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2])
```

Otherwise the talk index positions doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

`.concatenate` Just appends lists/arrays.

Maybe an unconventional way to go about it, but you could repeat the `[0 1]` pattern for the `len` of the shortest array, using `numpy.repeat` and then add repeated `1` values for the difference of the two arrays?

```
if len(h1) > len(h2):
   temp = len(h2)
else:
   temp = len(h1)

diff = abs(h1-h2)

for i in range(temp):
   A = numpy.repeat(0, 1)

for i in range(diff):
   B = numpy.repeat(1)

C = numpy.concatenate((A,B), axis=0)
```

Maybe not the most dynamic or kindest way to go about this but if your solution requires just that, then it could do the job in the meantime.

Comment: Another method can be to create an empty array, find the difference of the two arrays and use a for loop that iterates over this distance, then use two `.append` calls in succession and then just add the remaining 'len' of "1's".

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,).

Comment: Try `axis=None` and check size of the two arrays